# gatsby config throws 'IntrospectionQuery' error

Tags: gatsby

I have gatsby-config.js that has the following:

```
{
  resolve: gatsby-source-graphql,
  options: {
    typeName: racing,
    fieldName: 'members',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/members',
  },
},
{
  resolve: gatsby-source-graphql,
  options: {
    typeName: racing,
    fieldName: 'teams',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/teams',
  },
},
```

On startup I get an error:

```
    "gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Server response was missing for query 'IntrospectionQuery'.
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my gatsby configuration. I have not see this error before.

Comment: I'm getting this too now while trying to use Local By Flywheel's "Live Link" as my graphql source url. Did you ever figure it out yourself?

Comment: Not yet. But I have been working a lot with Next.js so I have not focused on it as much. Sorry.